# Calendar.getInstance thread safety

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

If I have a following method; is a call to [`Calendar.getInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) thread-safe?

```
 public Date currentTime() {
    Date d = null;
    synchronized(this){
        d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }
    return d;
 }
```

My understanding is `Calendar.getInstance()` isn't thread safe so following method can't be thread safe. Is it correct?

```
public Date currentTime() {
    return Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

}
```

I understand [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is promoted as a best practice for date-time APIs but here I am stuck with standard java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

Comment: Why wouldn't you get the Calendar once and hold that in the outer class, then inside getTime() you will just get using the reference you already have?

Comment: It is a shame you cannot make use of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Thread-safety is a major design goal for Joda-Time. If you can use Java 8, look for the new bundled [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) which is inspired by Joda-Time and defined by JSR 310.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, `Calendar.getInstance()` is thread-safe because each call creates and returns a new instance. You're not gaining anything by synchronizing or by storing the value returned by `getTime()` in a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you mean by thread safe in this context? you are not modifying any variable and the time is managed by the system. So any call to that method will give you a the current time of your system. No need to synchonise it on my opinion.